# What is meant by static and dynamic loads in electrical drives?

Tags: load

What is the definition of a static load and a dynamic load when it comes to electrical drives? Can someone give some examples for both types of loads?

Comment: Static, in any context, means "doesn't change". " dynamic" means the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic load is meant a torque required to accelerate/decelerate the mass/inertia. A static load would be some dead weight, for example the torque to suspend a mass of Z-axis. Other than this kind of loads we also have friction, and of course a mechanical load that is doing some work.